# Play PSOne games with analog sticks on the PSVita

Tags: ps-vita, psone-classics

I'd like to use the analog sticks of the PSVita when playing PSOne games but don't know how to do this. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read on the PS forum that it all depends if the PS One game you're playing on your PS vita, PS3 or PSP supports analog sticks or just digital.  So if it supports Analog then you can change the settings to use the sticks and digital is present if it doesn't.  If it DOES, just do this:

While you're in your PS One game, hold your finger on the ps vita Front Screen for a few seconds until the menu select screen appears to make your changes.  Now choose *Controller Settings* then choose *Switch Modes* then pick *Analog*.

You can also adjust the screen size of the game by selecting *Other Settings* in the menu select screen.  You have a choice for *Original* (which is the default TV screen size), *Normal* (which fits the screen height retaining 4:3 ratio), *Zoom* (zooms into the pictures cuting the top and bottom of the screen), and *Full* (which will stretches the picture to fill the Vita screen fully)

One more thing; the top half of the back touch screen has been assigned as L2 and R2 and the bottom half of the back touch screen is assigned as L3 and R3 because PSPs and Vitas don't have these buttons and the new rear screen on the Vita makes up for this issue.  So games like *legacy of kain: soul reaver* uses the back touch screen to activate the camera angles.

Comment: Hold the PS logo button, not the front screen.